# SQL Server: adding rows/tables with the same columns

Tags: sql-server, excel, import

I have two tables in SQL Server and both of those tables have the same headers, which means its the same columns, but since I added them from Excel, it means that I was not able to import them as one table, since it is more then 1 million rows.

So now I have one table with a bit less than a million rows and one with like 400000 rows and actually it should be one table, but Excel only allows around one million.

I have them both imported into SQL Server and actually I really want them to be both in one table like union.

The question is how to do it.

I just want to put one of them below the other since it is exactly the same column header.

Comment: Could share with us the structure of the tables,please?

Comment: you need to use "insert select" statement: insert into table1 select f1,f2,f3 from table2

Answer (score 2):

What you should have done was import the first sheet, and create the table at the same time, and then import the second sheet into the existing table, in a separate import process. Or, if you were using SSIS, you could have used a Union Data Transformation to "combine" the 2 datasets into one, and then insert all the data into a single table.

You can, however, easily get the data into one table. **Assuming** you want to retain `Table1` and that `Table1` and `Table2` do indeed have the same definitions (and don't have `IDENTITY` columns) you can just do the following:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Table1
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Table2;

DROP TABLE dbo.Table2;
```

Now all your data is in one table, `Table1`.